# что не так?(задача от Яндекс.Практикум)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Задача
Очеловечим Анфису. Пусть она округляет точные значения так, как это делают люди. Точное значение — дробь — хранится в переменной temperature_exact. Выведите на экран строку вида За окном 39.3 градусов Цельсия. Это почти 40
Анфиса должна взять точное значение, отбросить знаки после запятой, добавить единицу и сообщить примерное значение, округлённое «вверх» — до ближайшего большего целого числа. Его Анфиса сохраняет в переменной temperature_approx.

```py
temperature_exact = '39.3' 
temperature_approx = int(flot(temperature_exact)) + 1
print("За окном " + temperature_exact + " градусов Цельсия. Это почти " + str(temperature_approx) + ".")
```

Answer (score 1):

Опечатались в названии класса `float` (у Вас `flot`).

***Замените на:***

```py
temperature_approx = int(float(temperature_exact)) + 1
```

Comment: Есть же функция округления вверх...

Comment: @eri Есть... Но как это касается ошибки автора? Это была очевидная опечатка, и я на неё указал.

Answer (score 0):

я поняла в чем ошибка)

```py
temperature_exact = '39.3' 
temperature_approx = int(float(temperature_exact)) + 1     
print("За окном " + temperature_exact + " градусов Цельсия. Это почти " + str(temperature_approx))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Пусть она округляет точные значения так, как это делают люди.

Ваше округление работает не совсем корректно: вы отбрасываете дробную часть и добавляете 1. Это точно сработает неправильно, если число изначально целое.
К тому же, округлять числа вниз лучше не приведением типов, а делением нацело на 1

Как насчёт такого метода округления:

```py
temperature_exact = '39.3' 
temperature_approx = int((float(temperature_exact) + .5)  // 1)
print("За окном " + temperature_exact + " градусов Цельсия. Это почти " + str(temperature_approx))
```

Примеры округления по такому принципу:

```
35.0 ~ 35
35.3 ~ 35
35.5 ~ 36
35.7 ~ 36
36.0 ~ 36
```

Т.е. соблюдается принцип математического округления.